# Сложная выборка данных из БД SQL Server

Tags: sql, запрос, group-by, выборка

У меня есть большая база данных. Она локальная поэтому я не могу скрины принести. Итак

В базе есть
таблица **Users**
Поля **id, name**

Таблица **Clients**
Поля **id, user_id, name**

Таблица **Sessions**
Поля **id, client_id, description**

Таблица **SessionMeta**
поля **id, user_id, session_id, status**

Все таблицы связаны соответствующими ключами

Короче мне нужно посчитать сколько у каждого Пользователя по каждому из его Клиентов всего Сессий и Сессий со статусом = 2 из SessionMeta таблицы.

Это не лень, я просто реально запутался и у меня взрывается голова. Я пытался делать через Inner JOIN но с SQL не на проф уровне работаю.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сформировать такой сложный запрос. Какие команды использовать и в каком порядке. Большое спасибо.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/)

Comment: В следующий раз оформляй вопрос корректно, а то минусов нахватаешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вопрос так решается:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.name,
    c.id,
    c.name,
    COUNT(s.id) AS SessionCount 
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Clients c ON c.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN Sessions s ON s.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, c.id, c.name
```

Второй так:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.name,
    c.id,
    c.name,
    COUNT(s.id) AS SessionCount 
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Clients c ON c.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN Sessions s ON s.client_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN SessionMeta sm ON sm.session_id = s.id AND sm.status = 2 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, c.id, c.name
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) Я побегу попробую